# ADF output text doesn't display?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

this is ADF outputText

```
<af:outputText value="#{Signup.otput}"  id="ot1"/>
```

there is a button when click the outputText should fill and it attached with method like #{bean name.method name}

code in method :

```
boolean b =true;  
if(b){  
    setOtput("true");  
}
```

properties code

```
public void setOtput(String otput) {  
    this.otput = otput;  
}  
public String getOtput() {  
    return otput;  
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your method is getting called? try to debug the code or just print something inside the method.

Comment: @amishra what do you mean by calling method is there extra step after attatch it with the button

Comment: I meant, check if the code inside method is executed on button click. Could you also post jsf code for button? will be easier to analyze the issue

Comment: button code #{Signup.Signup_action}

Comment: please post the code for the button and its actionlistener

Comment: If the button's partialSubmit property is set to true, it should be added into outputText's partialTriggers property. What about yours?

Comment: @Amrola i don't know what is the use of actionlistener should i but something in it because it's empty

Comment: @GökhanÇoban partialSubmit  of button is true but for output Text its empty

Comment: please post your code so that i could help

Comment: @Amrola if you speak at button code which execute when clicked its up in the question begin with boolean b = true ;

Comment: @user2270924 Do you use Jdeveloper? If so, click to edit button for the partialTriggers property of the output text and select the popup, you should see the id of the popup in output text's partialTriggers property.

Comment: @GökhanÇoban thanks for helping it works when i put the id of button